# unwanted characters inside the Datatable

Tags: vb.net

I want to review an excel file after importing it from excel. And save the Excel file in `datatable`.
Also there might be unwanted Symbols or characters that I want to delete inside the `Datatable`
Symbols are not desirable {' / # ] [ $ % () ! "}

My unsuccessful method of identifying the symbol

```vb
For i = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1

    If DT Is Nothing Then
        Exit For : Exit Sub
    End If

    If DT.Rows(i).Item(i).ToString.Contains("'") Then
        MsgBox("UNWANTED CHARE" & "EXCEL ROW NO" & DT.Rows(i).Item(i).ToString)
    Else
        MsgBox("GOOD")

    End If
Next
```

Comment: you need nested loop

Comment: The check for `If DT Is Nothing Then` should be *before* the loop (and it won't need the `Exit For`).

Comment: Note that `DT.Rows(i).Item(i)` means *only* Item **i** of Row **i**. As T.S. implied, you need to check *each* item in Row **i**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s As String = "Ma!r]y/ O'(B]r)ie%$#n"
    ' symbols not desired {' / # ] [ $ % () ! "}
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "[\{'/\#\]\[\$%\(\)!""}]", "")
    Debug.Print(s)
End Sub
```

Produced Mary OBrien in the Immediate window.
In the second string...
The outer [  ] enclose the set to be recognized.
The \ escape certain characters which would be recognized as special characters in regex.